# Anyone know why I'm getting a "Process finished with exit code 0"?

Tags: python, truthiness

I'm trying to run this program but for some reason, whenever I enter 0, the program stops running. I expect a "You've guessed too low, please try again " as the input is less than the random number generated. Can anyone help and explain? Also, feel free to critique my code so that I can make it better. Much appreciated.

```
# Generate random number for player to guess.
import random

number = random.randint(1, 3)
print(number)

# Ask player's name and have player guess the number.
welcomeUser = input("Hi, welcome to 'Guess a Number!'. Please tell us your name ")

userName = str(welcomeUser)
userGuess = int((input("Guess a number from 1 - 3 ")))

# Cycle through player's guesses until player enters correct number.
while userGuess:
    if userGuess > number:
        print("You've guess too high, please try again ")
        userGuess = int(input("Guess a number from 1 - 3 "))
        if userGuess == number:
            print("Congratulations! You've guessed correctly! ")
            break
    elif userGuess < number or userGuess == 0:
        print("You've guessed too low, please try again ")
        userGuess = int(input("Guess a number from 1 - 3 "))
        if userGuess == number:
            print("Congratulations! You've guessed correctly! ")
            break
    else:
        print("Congratulations " + userName + "! " + "You've guessed correctly! ")
        break
```

Comment: In a Boolean context such as a loop condition, 0 evaluates to False, so your code never enters the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0` is falsey, i.e. it evaluates to `False` in a boolean expression. Therefore, the `while` loop starting with

```
while userGuess:
```

will be skipped if `userGuess` is `0`. It doesn't look like you need to check for any conditions in your loop, so changing that to

```
while True:
```

should suffice. BTW, `Process finished with exit code 0` just means the program exited without any errors.

Comment: Awesome! I just made the change and it's working. So any 0 input in a while statement would make it False, thus exiting the program?

Comment: @Mir Pretty much. For example, do `print(bool(0))`. It's `False`, so your loop would turn into `while False:` which will very obviously never execute.

Answer (score 1):

in python 0 equals "false". So when you enter a "0" userGuess becomes false and the while loop terminates.
Better introduce a new variable:

```
continueProgram = True
while continueProgram :
    if userGuess > number:
        print("You've guess too high, please try again ")
        userGuess = int(input("Guess a number from 1 - 3 "))
        if userGuess == number:
            print("Congratulations! You've guessed correctly! ")
            continueProgram = False
    elif userGuess < number or userGuess == 0:
        print("You've guessed too low, please try again ")
        userGuess = int(input("Guess a number from 1 - 3 "))
        if userGuess == number:
            print("Congratulations! You've guessed correctly! ")
            continueProgram = False
    else:
        print("Congratulations " + userName + "! " + "You've guessed correctly! ")
        continueProgram = False
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: You can't assign to `continue`, a keyword in Python.

Comment: oops :) yeah just rename the variable

Comment: @AlinaJ Also, in Python `true` is `True` and `false` is `False`. Also, a quick tip, you can edit your answer to make it better with the `edit` button in the bottom left!

Comment: Something looks strange with your indentation. Can you check it?